# Inequality for $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Consider:

$\frac{x}{3} - 1 = -\frac{13}{12}$

The answer is $-3 < x < 0$. All the options are inequalities. I feel like the problem is missing something because I don't see where an inequality would come into play. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The answer I got was $x=-1/4$ So its technically valid to say that $-3<x<0$ since the answer lies in that interval. Do the other possible answers exclude $-1/4$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x}{3} - 1 = -\frac{13}{12}$$
$$\frac{x}{3}=-\frac{1}{12}$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{4}$$

The solution clearly satisfies $-3\lt x\lt0$. That is what the option probably meant. It was probably given so to ensure that the question is solved rather than substituting the options to check which satisfies the equation.